# Show dropdown list when combobox has focus

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

Is it possible to put a single bit of code on an Access form that would automatically show the dropdown list whenever any combobox on the form has focus?

I know I can automatically show the dropdown list whenever a combobox has focus by using the event below. But, if possible, I would prefer to not have to put that line of code on each combobox since I have so many.

```
Private Sub combobox_GotFocus()
    'When the combobox receives focus
    'display in drop down position
    Me.combobox.Dropdown
End Sub
```

My database has dozens of forms in it with dozens of comboboxes on each form.

Comment: No, there is not a 'single bit of code' that will accomplish this for all comboboxes. Each will need the event code.

Comment: Sorry to object but you can

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Class to Handle Access Form Control Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23522230/creating-a-class-to-handle-access-form-control-events)

Comment: Sorry @Storax but I'm not very good a VBA, I looked at the provided link but I'm not entirely sure where to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class named cComboBox

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents mComboBox As Access.ComboBox

Private Sub mComboBox_GotFocus()
    mComboBox.Dropdown
End Sub

Public Function AddCtl(nCtl As Access.ComboBox) As Access.ComboBox
    Set mComboBox = nCtl
    mComboBox.OnGotFocus = "[Event Procedure]"
    'mComboBox.OnChange = "[Event Procedure]"
    Set AddCtl = mComboBox
End Function
```

and add the following code to your Form

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim myCBs As New Collection

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim myCB As cComboBox

Dim ctl As Access.Control
    For Each ctl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "ComboBox" Then
            Set myCB = New cComboBox
            myCB.AddCtl ctl
            myCBs.Add myCB
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That worked beautifully and saved me a ton of time!

Comment: @Storax; Could you please explain the purpose of the line `Set AddCtl = mComboBox` in the `Function AddCtl()` inside the Class `cComboBox`?

Comment: @Gene: No purpose at all, I just copied and modified the code from the link above. So, it is probably better to use a Set property instead. On the other hand it does not do any real harm.

Comment: @Storax; No, not that... I just thought it is not needed at all since there is no use for the function's return anyway: it matters not if `AddCtl` is assigned or not, whatsoever.

Comment: @Gene: Right, you could remove the line `Set AddCtl = mComboBox` completely and everything would still work.